# How do I inherit behaviour of another directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is really a rather generic question, but as people on IRC appeared to have issues understanding what I was trying to do, I've provided some rather specific information in this post. The answer would likely be applicable to a far wider range of issues than just this specific one.

I'm looking to have one directive inherit behaviour of another directive, while also providing behaviour of its own. Below is an example case.

Say I have the following document:

```
<body ng-app="AppCore" dock-container>
    <pane dock="left" class="one">
        left
    </pane>
    <pane dock="fill" class="two" title="middle">
        <pane dock="top" class="four" height="100">
            middle top
        </pane>
        <pane dock="fill" class="five">
            middle fill
        </pane>
    </pane>
    <pane dock="right" class="three" title="whatever">
        right
    </pane>
</body>
```

Here, I have three different directives:

- **`pane`**: An element directive. This represents a UI element (a pane or 'panel', as the name implies).
- **`dock-container`**: An attribute directive. This acts as a modifier; it adds some bookkeeping data to the scope, and marks it as being a 'container'.
- **`dock`**: An attribute directive. This also acts as a modifier; it indicates that the element should be positioned relative to the nearest `dock-container` parent - 'docking' here refers to making the element 'stick' to a side of the nearest container (or fill up the remaining space).

Now, the problem is that a `pane` should also implicitly be a `dock-container` - that is, it should behave exactly the same as an element with the `dock-container` directive would, in addition to `pane`-specific behaviour.

However, in the interest of clean markup, I don't want to have to explicitly specify `dock-container` on every `pane` - it should implicitly inherit from `dock-container` without having to actually specify the `dock-container` directive.

In other words, I'm looking to make my `pane` directive behave as if it were like this:

```
<pane dock-container>
```

... while it **actually** says this in the document:

```
<pane>
```

I don't particularly care *how* the `pane` directive inherits its behaviour from the `dock-container` directive, even if it means having the `pane` directive add the `dock-container` directive itself before Angular finishes processing the element. Ideally, the `link` function of the `dock-container` directive, not just the controller, would *also* be applied to the `pane`.

I am currently using `element.parent().controller('dockContainer')` to find the nearest `dock-container` from a `dock` directive - for this to work, the controller that I've defined for the `dock-controller` directive would have to be present on the `pane` element, regardless of the method of inheritance.

If your suggested inheritance implementation requires a different method of finding the nearest `dock-container` (or `pane`), that's fine too - the problem here is just the inheritance, the rest can be changed to accommodate the solution to this problem.

The following are **not** suitable options:

- Copy-pasting the code for `dock-container` to the `pane` directive. I want to keep code duplication to a minimum, and it's quite possible that other directives in the future should also inherit from `dock-container`.
- Manually adding `dock-container` to every `pane` element - this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The code I'm working on is meant to be used as a reusable set of directives, and I aim to keep the syntax as clean as possible. *Every* `pane` should inherit the `dock-container` behaviour, so there's no added value in requiring it to be specified explicitly.
- Anything that overrides the behaviour for the `pane` directive. The `dock-container` behaviour should be an *addition*, not a replacement. The `pane` directive will also have some specific behaviour of its own, that the `dock-container` directive itself does not have.
- Anything that makes it impossible for an element to have both a `dock` and `dock-container` directive - the search for the 'nearest `dock-container`' starts at the parent of the element, so an element will never be its *own* `dock-container`.
- Anything that changes the type of element. The `pane` element should stay a `pane` element.

Answer (score 2):

As a simpler alternative to my other answer, if you don't need there to be a `pane` element in the final rendered DOM, and no other directive has a template on the element or uses transclusion, then you can just use standard transclusion to dynamically add the `dock-container` directive:

```
app.directive('pane', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div dock-container ng-transclude></div>',
    link: function() {
      // Any special behaviour for a pane element
    }
  };
});
```

[As seen in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9RVRWoKYECh4a9U67CL6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

> even if it means having the pane directive add the dock-container directive itself before Angular finishes processing the element

You can do this by

- Setting a very high priority to the `pane` directive
- Set it to `terminal: true` to stop other directives being compiled after this one
- In the linking function add `dock-container` attribute, and then recompile the element, passing the priority of the `pane` directive as the third parameter. This will allow all other directives with a lower priority, such as `dock-container`, and any other directive on the element, to run.

Example code of this is as follows

```
app.directive('pane', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    priority: 9999,
    terminal: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transclude) {
      element.attr('dock-container', '');
      $compile(element, null, 9999)(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

[An example of this can be seen here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QquEa5UqiIuD93TAxu8h?p=preview)

I've seen a few other suggestions about how to dynamically adding directives to elements, but this way minimises DOM manipulation, and as long as this really is the top priority directive on the element, it ensures that other directives on the same element only get compiled once, after the dynamic directive has been added.

---

As as sidenote/recommendation, unless I had a good reason too, in order to KISS I would just have both `pane` and `dock-container` explicitly on the same element. Yes, the template is a bit longer, but it explicitly shows what directives are in play on the element, and the interaction between the 2 directives is much more standard.

Comment: This solution appears to kind-of-work - the `dock-container` directive is added and processed correctly, but I'm now running into the following error: `Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <pane-contents ng-transclude="ng-transclude" dock="fill" height="auto" class="ng-scope">`. Is it possible that the second $compile interferes with the `transclude` property? The `pane-contents` directive exists inside the `pane` template.

Comment: @SvenSlootweg It's hard to say without seeing the code. Post a plunker?

Comment: I've created a reduced testcase at http://plnkr.co/edit/x0HRNj01TVAdwkjrdR9n?p=preview - it doesn't have any of the styling or dockContainer-finding, it just sets a number of classes to demonstrate the functionality. If you look at the console log, the error I mentioned should appear. As you can see, aside from that one error, it appears to work correctly.

Comment: Ah... You're using transclusion on the `pane`. I suspect this throws the error due to the fact when it manually calls `$compile`, there is still an `ng-include` attribute in the DOM. I think my other solution is better in this case, as it keeps it simple, although there won't be a `pane` element in the DOM any more.

Comment: I hadn't gotten around to responding to your other solution yet, but I need the `pane` element to stay a `pane` element. Is there any way to make it work with this solution? It appears to still process the transclude anyway, so - unless I'm missing something - manually removing whatever is triggering it again should solve the problem. I'm just not quite sure what that "whatever" is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a template with `'<dock-container/>'` within your `pane` directive defintion...

```
{
    template: '<dock-container/>',
    replace: true,
}
```

And if `dockContainer` exposes a controller, you can reference it in your `dock` directive something like...

```
{
    template: '<dock-container/>',
    replace: true,
    require: '^dockContainer',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, dockContainerController) {
    }
}
```

But please consult the docs for the appropriate `require` syntax, ie the `^`.